# How Can I count unique visitors to my website, i am supplying just list of ips through loki but I am struggling to create the right query

Tags: grafana, grafana-loki

I am logging nginx IPs access log to a file and transport it using promtail to loki to grafana all self hosted.

I've been doing it for past few hours, but I struggle to understand the right query commands: it should just be sum or count, right? But I never seem to have the right field or seem to do it right. I would like it to be the ever rising graph or a gauge.

```
sum(count_over_time({filename="/var/log/nginx/akomercyjni.pl_access.log"}  
| regexp `(?P<zdalneip>[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*)` 
| regexp `(?P<kreska_kreska>- - )` 
| regexp `(?P<dataigodz>\[[0-9]{1,2}/[a-zA-Z]{3}/[0-9]{4}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2}:[0-9]{1,2} \+[0-9]{4})\] ` 
| regexp `(?P<postlubget>GET|POST )` 
| regexp `(?P<urlek> \/ HTTP)` 
| urlek=" / HTTP" or urlek=" /index.html"[$__interval])) 
by (zdalneip)
```

That was on a regular log hence all the parsing, I expected to get a gauge with the number of IPs that touched my '/' rather than other random connections that seem to appear in there, so I get "real people", but i got a bunch of small gauges with this,
now i have this:

```
sum(count_over_time({filename="/var/log/nginx/akomercyjni.pl_access_justips.log"} [$__interval]))
```

but I am honestly at loss, also not sure what graph tye would be good for this either.

EDIT: solved by abandoning grafana, doing a log cat to sed the index page  that shows a visitor count now

Comment: If you want a single result with number of distinct `zdalneip` in your logs, you need one more wrapping count. Something along the lines of `count(count by (zdalneip) (count_over_time( ..your_log_selector.. [$__interval] ))`

Comment: this is missing an ending ) and in total just gets me a time series, or a ONE on a gauge.